# How to transition between running along joists to running perpendicular

Tags: electrical, wiring

Referring to picture provided, what is the best way to transition my SER cable from running with the ceiling joists to running perpendicular? I can't drill through every joist due to all the existing pipes, HVAC and wires. This 2-2-2-4 cable is feeding a sub panel in my attached garage, and where the cable is perpendicular through the last joist, it feeds directly straight into the garage.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The picture provided does not need a hole in "every joist" it needed one more hole in one more joist.

The best way to treat that problem is to drill that hole, missing the one visible or possibly more pipes invisible there. *For instance, run left along the face of the joist-with-hole until past the pipe, then drill through joist-with-awkwardly-attached-cable where the pipe is not in the way.*

If you have a long run (not pictured) where you need to run through many joists and have too many obstacles, transitioning to conduit or a conduit protective sleeve attached to the bottom of the joists is one of many methods, or building a lumber protective structure under the joists (ultimately a soffit, if you finish the basement ceiling) is another.

*However* 334.15(c) permits direct attachment to the joists for that cable size without additional protective measures. It might not be best, but it's adequate for code purposes.

Comment: I mean, clearly one hole was drilled, seems like it'd be facile to drill another one!, right?

Comment: If I don't go crazy with the 90 degree direction change, I guess I could just run it along the joist in the picture that already has the hole drilled in it.

Comment: 334.17(B) specifies that minimum bend radius (not diameter) shall be 5 times the cable diameter so that's exactly how crazy you can go with the 90 degree bend.

Comment: That may be easiest if you run the cable on the invisible face of *joist-with-awkwardly-attached-cable* rather than the visible face of *joist-with-hole* allowing you to use the full width of the joist bay to make the turn.

Comment: Attaching cables such as that to the bottom of joists is not permitted by code where I live, because they are clearly "subject to damage".

Comment: Is there anything that says the cable has to penetrate the joist at 90º?  You could drill your hole at 45º (as long as the length of the hole is less than the 1/3 joist height), offset to the left of the 90º hole in the joist by the wall.